# reset javascript code returned from ajax,

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

After an ajax call, I return in response HTML code with javascript code.
I put this javascript code inside div.
this javascript code has a function, this function content changed in every request ajax (the whole content inside div )

but when I call this function it still call the first code I request in ajax (if I request ajax multi times and this function change in every request)
the browser still preserves the old js script call by ajax.

how can I reset this code function or javascript in every ajax call?

Here is pseudo code:

page1.php

```html
echo "<script>
  function x() {
    console.log('1');
  }
</script>";
```

page2.php

```
echo "<script>
  function x(){
    console.log('2');
  }
</script>";
```

My Page

```html
<button onclick="setContent('page1.php')">fun1</>
<button onclick="setContent('page2.php')">fun2</>
<div id="content"></div>

<script>
  function setContent(url) {
  $.ajax({
    url: url, 
    type: "get",
    cache: false,               
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(resp) {
      $('#content').html(resp);
      x(); //it still call function x in page 1 (it duplicate)
    },
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please add the code necessary to enable others to understand the problem

Comment: `url: 'page1.php'` *probably* should be `url:url` - your code *as presented* always loads `page1.php`